# how to add functions to segue swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob, segue

How can I run this ad while the `segue` is running? `Segue` (modal) is working. I wrote it programatically. But when I tried to run the ad I couldn't. How can I run it?

```
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5378899862041789/2782958552")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())

        return interstitial
    }

    func getAd(){
        if (self.interstitial.isReady)
        {


 self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        self.interstitial = self.createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
}


@IBAction func webView(sender: UIButton) {
    getAd()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("mapView", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why are you presenting an ad during a segue?  Segues are meant to quickly transition from one view to another. Extra content should not be displayed.

Comment: After all, I left off the segues for ad and I did it with UIWebView

Comment: Why do couldn't you just use the built in ad view?

Comment: I used to want to display an interstitial ad before UIWebView appears. I used UIWebView to display a webpage.